# VS Code : Differences between options under File menu

Tags: menu, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In Visual Studio Code, as you might know, there are many options under File:

- Open file
- Open folder
- Open workspace
- Add folder to workspace

etc.

Could anyone please tell me the differences and benefits to choosing any of these over others?  VS Code clearly sits gently on top of the File system, and is not heavily configured (say like, VS 2017, NetBeans, Eclipse, etc.) - it is of course closer to its sibling, Atom.

But I'm not entirely sure the advantages or recommendations related to, for example, Add Folder to Workspace vs just Open Folder, saving the workspace (or not), etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

-J

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Firstly open file is just the option to edit or open a file.

**2.** Secondly opening a folder is the option to import your project directory in the editor.

**3.** Then comes the workspace option which is quite similar to the open folder option with the difference that every workspace has its custom working settings.

*VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:*

**User Settings -** Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.

**Workspace Settings -** Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.

Workspace settings override user settings.

For more details you can refer to [VS code settings (docs)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)